# Can a web graphic's color be an inverse of whatever's behind it?

Tags: html, css, graphics, svg, svg-filters

If creating a web graphic that's meant to be used in many places and overlaid on top of other elements, is it possible for the graphic to composite with whatever's beneath it -- like setting a Photoshop layer to be "Difference" -- such that its colors invert?

Specifically, picture a "Left" and "Right" image arrow that could be placed on top of an image  carousel. Many images could appear beneath it and, if the arrows are lightly colored on a lightly colored image, they may be difficult to see. As such, an image whose color is the difference of what's behind it would turn dark on a light background.

I'm picturing doing this with an SVG, potentially, but if it could be accomplished with a png or other bitmap of sorts, that'd be neat too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on bleeding edge browsers you have the option of using CSS blend modes, see [this tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/basics-css-blend-modes/).

For more details, see the [specification](http://dev.w3.org/fxtf/compositing-1/), which covers html, svg and css.

Comment: Yep, I think that's exactly it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

yes it can, but the support is really poor if you want a CSS only solution. You had the inverse filter on IE versions and now you have Webkit support, but that's about it. However, you can use [JQuery Invert](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/373253) plugin by Paul Irish. It does exactly what you want, and obviously has better support than CSS

Comment: This would change the colors of the element, would it not? Instead of compositing color in relation to what's beneath it?